# C# SQL Login form error incorrect syntax

Tags: c#, sql, database, select, sqldatareader

I am trying to make a login form application that when a user types into the two text boxes and presses the button my application checks the Username and Password columns of my TeacherDetails table and if they are present in the table it displays that they are correct.

(My INSERT signup code works perfectly)

I can't seem to find why my attempt for doesn't work when I press the button an error comes up saying:

> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ','.

I'd very much appreciate anyone who could help me out with why it doesn't work or any simpler ways of doing what I'm trying to do. Thank you!!!

Here's my code attempt:

```
 private void TeacherLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connect.Open();

    SqlCommand command10 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ([Username], [Password]) 
    FROM TeacherDetails 
    WHERE ([Username]='" + this.usernameTlogin.Text + "' 
    AND [Password]= '" + this.passwordTlogin.Text +"');", connect);

    SqlDataReader reader;
    reader = command10.ExecuteReader();
    int count = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }
    if( count == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct");
    }
    else if (count > 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("BEEP BOOP ERROR");
    }
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect");
    }
}
```

And here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TeacherDetails] (
[TeacherID]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[First Name]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Last Name]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Title]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Username]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Password]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Email Address] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TeacherID] ASC)
```

);

Comment: Please use parameterized queries.  You are ripe for a sql injection using concatination.

Comment: @paqogomez Probably worth mentioning that storing passwords in plaintext is a bad idea too...

Comment: @DGibbs Do you mean storing the passwords in a non hidden way? How would I tackle this?

Comment: @mot375 using the debugger and the quickwatch to inspect the values I believe that you could have quickly spotted the issue.. do not just write what I like to call `Code and Go` meaning writing the code and then just running the application without stepping through the code and or debugging if you want pass words then you need to look up how to encrypt passwords in database come on .. this is what google is here for

Comment: @paqogomez okay I'm not 100% sure what that is could you please give me an example?

Comment: @mot375 Your passwords are stored in plaintext (un-encrypted). If your database is ever compromised your passwords will be easily readable. They should be [hashed and salted](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm), only comparing the encrypted versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis around your `SELECT` clause:

```
SqlCommand command10 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Username], [Password] FROM TeacherDetails WHERE ([Username]='" + this.usernameTlogin.Text + "' AND [Password]= '" + this.passwordTlogin.Text +"');", connect);
```

**Edit** *(due to the backlash over not providing details on what else is wrong with the question)*

1. Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) due to simply concatenating the user input into your SQL query.  For example, if a user enters:

> '); drop table TeacherDetails--

Your SQL query will be turned into:

```
SELECT [Username], [Password] 
FROM TeacherDetails 
WHERE ([Username]=''); drop table TeacherDetails --' AND [Password]= '');", connect);
```

Resulting in your TeacherDetails table being deleted.  This is just an example of what could happen, they could potentially `SELECT * FROM TeacherDetails` giving them access to all of your usernames and passwords, which leads to the next point.

2. You are storing your passwords in plain text.  If someone gets access to your database (SQL Injection or otherwise), it's not going to take *any* work to get usernames and passwords.

So, you could use parameterized queries, stored procedures, or an ORM (Entity Framework, LINQtoSQL, etc...)

Comment: Please dont suggest using concatenation in sql.  Rewrite it to use parameterized queries.

Comment: I'm answering the question he asked, not providing a solution he didn't ask.  Thanks.

Comment: And thanks for the downvote, this *is* the cause of his problem.

Comment: @Tom read up on Sql Injection regardless of downvotes or not it's not good practice to use concatenation in regards to sql parameterized queries are usually the best way to go. and if you want even better suggestion I would suggest creating a stored procedure.

Comment: @MethodMan, I know what SQL injection is, I know what stored procedures are, and I know how to prevent SQL injection.  The question asks why he is getting the error he is getting, and I answer that question.

Comment: you may have answered it .. but you should have recommended it that's all I am saying @Tom.. chill is the word of the day..

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues here. Firstly, to answer your actual question - your select syntax is incorrect. You shouldn't bracket the columns in your select list:

```
SqlCommand command10 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Username], [Password] FROM TeacherDetails ...
```

BUT, there are (arguably more serious) issues here too.

Your code is open to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as you are using string concatenation. You should be using [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead.

Finally, you're comparing plain text passwords which means your passwords are stored in plaintext. It's good practice to store your passwords in an encrypted manner then compare encrypted strings against each other. That way if your database is ever comprimised your passwords are safe(r).